# ActionListener compilation error - ; expected

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

I am trying to open an application from a jbutton b1 using actionlistener:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)// outside the class
    {
        if(ae.getSource() == b1)//b1 is the button
        {
            try         
            {
                d.open(f);//f has the path to the exe file
            }
            catch(Exception ex) 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(OpenApps.this,ex.getMessage(),"Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I add the action listener:

```
b1.add ActionListener(this);// inside the class
```

It gives an error:

```
; expected in line b1.add ActionListener(this);
```

Please help.

Comment: Could you show us the whole class? do you remember to `implements ActionListener` ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you dont have any space between b1.addActionListener(this);

add and ActionListener.

addActionListener is the method for adding the actionlistener.

Comment: It worked by removing spacing thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code example of

```
b1.add ActionListener(this);// inside the class
```

You have a space between `add` and `ActionListenr`.

```
b1.add ActionListener(this);// inside the class
      ^--- This won't help...
```

Try,

```
b1.addActionListener(this);// inside the class
```

Instead

Comment: It worked by removing spacing thanks..

Answer (score 1):

```
b1.add ActionListener(this);// inside the class
```

Remove the spacing!

```
b1.addActionListener(this);// inside the class
```